# CGBitmapContextCreate invalid data bytes/row

Tags: ios, avfoundation, swift2

I want to use an example from Apple's developer pages. [Apple Dev Pages on AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1702/_index.html)

Now, I used the `imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer` method as the documentation explains. I am writing in Swift, so I converted as well as I could from Obj-C to Swift 2.

I can't help but receive errors about `invalid data bytes/row: should be at least 7680 for 8 integer bits/component, 3 components, kCGImageAlphaPremultipledFirst` and `CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0.`

```
func imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBufferRef) -> UIImage {
    let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, 0)
    let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer!)
    let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer!)
    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer!)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer!)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue)
    let qImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, 0)
    let image = UIImage(CGImage: qImage!)
    return(image)
  }
```

And this is how I call that method:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    print("Delegate called")
    let image = imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    print(image)
  }
```

I have absolutely no clue about how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the list of acceptable parameters to `CGBitmapContextCreate` at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB
2. Check if your captured buffer is 8 bit/component RGB and not some other format.
3. Check if the input buffer lacks alpha-component. Then you should use kCGImageAlphaNone.

Comment: 1: I did check this and it seems to be correct by using `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst` in `CGBitmapContextCreate`.
2: How do I confirm this?
3: How would I check this? The imagery comes straight from the camera, so it should have alpha-component, right?

Comment: 2: Which format do you specify to when creating a `AVCaptureOutput`? E.g. what is `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.videoSettings[kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey]`? 3: A camera does not capture an alpha-component. Where would this data come from?

Comment: 2: I use `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` but I didn't set `.videoSettings` yet. I tried setting `output?.videoSettings[kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey] = kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA`, but that errors saying I can't assign `OSType`/`UInt32` to `AnyObject?`.

3: I don't really understand this, to be honest, I'm sorry. Could you please explain?

Comment: I hope you can still help me out?

Comment: Try wrapping it, `... = Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)`.